# Rodar programa dentro Try/Catch

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exceção, try-catch

Trabalhando com o Visual Studio, quando acontece algum erro enquanto o programa está rodando o programa trava e não se consegue ver aonde o programa travou e só apareceu aquela tela de erro.

Para pegar aonde acontecem estes erros utilizamos o `try catch`, assim conseguimos capturar aonde e porque o erro aconteceu.

Uma possibilidade para nunca ter este problema é colocar o programa inteiro dentro de um `try catch`, porém sei que não é uma boa prática.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //Todo o programa
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Capturar os erros
        }
    }
}
```

Quais os problemas ou por que não deixar o programa inteiro dentro de um `try catch`?

Comment: Nunca faça isso, vai dar uma lentidão que dá para ir na lua e voltar e o programa ainda não finalizou suas tarefas.

Comment: Essa resposta pode te ajudar [Para que servem os Blocos Try/Catch e quando devem ser utilizados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58536/para-que-servem-os-blocos-try-catch-e-quando-devem-ser-utilizados/424523#424523)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como é possível perceber lendo o final [desse artigo](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/490765/If-else-instead-of-try-catch), os dois principais argumentos são **desempenho** e **integridade**.

#### Desempenho

A primeira e mais óbvia razão para não se usar um `try/catch` no programa inteiro é que, gerar uma `exception` é bem mais custoso do que controlar o trabalho fluxo do programa com `if/else`.
No caso de nenhuma exceção ser lançada, o `if/else` realmente torna o fluxo mais lento, entranto, caso uma única exceção seja lançada, o tempo de execução gasto pra tratar essa exceção é equivalente a diversos blocos `if/else`.

#### Integridade

A segunda razão, um pouco menos óbvia, é que, caso você tenha realizado qualquer coisa antes da exceção ser lançada, tudo que acontece **até chegar** chegar na exceção é executado, o que torna a execução de parte do código inútil.
Enquanto isso, no `if/else` essas linhas que seriam *inúteis* são desprezadas antes de serem executadas.

#### Outras questões

Além desses dois problemas, [nessa resposta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/107727) ele ainda trata da questão semântica. Exceções são para casos excepcionais, logo devem ser usados quando você **não espera** que vá acontecer um erro ali. Enquanto `if/else` deverão ser utilizados para controlar o fluxo do programa, tornando, inclusive, a sua leitura mais natural e a manutenção do código mais fácil.

Um bom exemplo de quando devemos usar `try/catch` é quando estamos tentando carregar um arquivo, podem acontecer falhas alheias ao seu programa, como, por exemplo, o arquivo não existir mais ou acontecer algum problema na leitura da unidade de armazenamento, nesses casos em que se espera o sucesso e você **não tem como prever** o erro é onde o `try/catch` deve ser utilizado.

Comment: Felipe Avelar. Se são usados em casos que não esperamos um erro, como saber quando colocar? Tem um exemplo de situação que você sempre usa o try/catch? Acho que isso complementaria a resposta também. Obrigado.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo, vê se a edição melhorou um pouco a resposta.

Answer (score 5):

Não. Esta não é a forma de fazer isso.

Existe maleficios de colocar o programa inteiro dentro de um bloco try catch porém não vou fazer referencia a eles mas te mostrar o jeito certo de fazer.

Existe na plataforma .NET um jeito de registrar um trecho de código que será disparado sempre que uma exceção não for tratada e chegar ao topo da pilha de excução sem tratamento.

O código a seguir, extraído de uma [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133199/net-global-exception-handler-in-console-application) no stackoverflow.com, exemplifica o uso:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionTrapper;
        throw new Exception("Kaboom");
    }

    static void UnhandledExceptionTrapper(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
}
```

O código que você registrar fará o papel da sua cláusula **catch** de um **try** que envolve a aplicação como um todo.

Answer (score 3):

Para evitar que todo o código esteja dentro de um try/catch você deve aprimorar seus testes para detectar falhas. Tudo deve ser validado seguindo boas técnicas de programação.
Portanto entradas de dados devem ser validadas, chamadas de sistema, retornos de funções direitos de acesso a recursos, etc...
Aplicação de melhores práticas pode ser de grande ajuda.
Algumas ferramentas podem ser vistas aqui : [Code Coverage for C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276829/code-coverage-for-c-net)

Comment: Concordo que testes e validações são essenciais e práticas de extrema importância, mas não com dizer que isso elimina a necessidade de um tratamento genérico *bugs*, já que os erros mais difíceis de achar são justamente os que estão mais escondidos e, nesse caso, seria necessário algum mecanismos de tratamento excepcional.