# Para que servem os Blocos Try/Catch e quando devem ser utilizados?

Tags: php, exceção, try-catch

Andei procurando algumas explicações sobre o assunto, mas não encontrei nenhuma que fosse simples e direta. Minha pergunta é : **Para que servem os Blocos Try/Catch e quando devem ser utilizados?**

Comment: Eu ia responder mas já tem uma resposta aceita, acho que não precisa mais.

Comment: Pode responder se quiseres, quanto mais melhor! hehe

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Bloco `try/catch` serve para tratamento de exceções, tratamento de códigos que podem não ser totalmente atendidos e gerarem alguma exceção/erro.

O `try` consegue recuperar erros que possam ocorrer no código fornecido em seu bloco.
O `catch` por sua vez faz o tratamento dos erros que aconteceram.

**Exemplo:**

```
try {
    //Esse código precisa de tratamento pois pode gerar alguma exceção
    $x = 1;
    if ($x === 1)
        throw new \Exception('X não pode ser 1');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

Além disso também temos um bloco chamado `finally` (PHP 5.5 ou superior), que fornecem instruções do que deve ser executado após o `try/catch` (normalmente liberação de recursos). Caso uma exceção seja capturada, o `finally` será executado somente após o termino das instruções fornecidas no `catch`. Caso nenhuma exceção seja gerada, o `finally` será executado após as instruções fornecidas no `try`.

**Exemplo:**

```
try {
    //Esse código precisa de tratamento pois pode gerar alguma exceção
    $variavel = AlgumaCoisa::pegarRecurso();
    if ($variavel->executarAlgumaCoisa())
        throw new \Exception('Erro: ' . $variavel->pegarErro());
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
} finally {
    $variavel->liberarRecurso(); 
}
```

Finalizando, erros gerados fora de um bloco `try/catch`, podem gerar mensagens inconvenientes aos usuários que utilizam seu sistema. Vamos a um exemplo:

```
//Nada antes
throw new Exception('teste');
//Nada depois
```

Caso o código acima seja executado, vai gerar uma mensagem de erro muito bonita na tela

```
//Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'teste' in ...
```

Answer (score 13):

Blocos de `try/catch` são blocos para tratar exceções que o programador não tem como prever que irão acontecer, erros em tempo de execução, que não há como o programador controlar, como por exemplo, o usuário perder a conexão com a internet. Esses comportamentos inesperados são tratados com o lançamento de **exceções**, essas exceções lançam erros, avisando que um comportamento inesperado aconteceu.

O bloco `try/catch` vai tratar essa parte "crítica" de código e tentar executá-lo, caso nenhum erro aconteça, o programa segue seu fluxo normal, senão ele entrará no bloco que se encontra dentro do `catch` para tratar o erro.

Em resumo, o `try/catch` serve para tratar comportamentos **inesperados**, entretanto ele é bem mais lento que controlar o fluxo de um programa com `if/else`, ou seja, deve ser utilizado preferencialmente quando o desenvolvedor **não tem como garantir** que aquele código será executado com sucesso.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, muito bem resumida e explicada.

Comment: O destaque em **inesperados** é um engano, até pelo fato de disparar uma exceção usando `throw new Exception('meu erro')` - o que torna o *inesperado* em esperado e controlado. (A não ser que tenha interpretado errado sua explicação...)

Comment: @PapaCharlie, o que eu quis dizer com inesperado, é que, mesmo que eu tenha o `throw`, esse lançamento não deve ocorrer e eu só vou "descobrir" isso em tempo de execução. Por isso eu usei o exemplo de perda de conexão. Já que um erro esperado pode ser tratado com fluxos de programa, como, por exemplo, uma divisão por zero.

Answer (score 7):

**Quando utilizar**

Você irá utilizar este bloco quando você usar algum método que lance uma CheckedException e quando você quer dar algum tratamento a exception.

Um bloco “try” é chamado de bloco “protegido” porque, caso ocorra algum problema com os comandos dentro do bloco, a execução desviará para os blocos “catch” correspondentes.

Necessitamos usar try, porque estamos fazendo operação de conversão, é uma maneira mais robusta de tratar possíveis erros no momento da conversão, por exemplo, não é possível converter um caractere “?” por um número, porém como a entrada de dados é liberada o usuário final poderá digitar algo inadequado, resultando em erro e quebra da execução do programa por falha, com o try podemos evitar esta queda brusca e então tratar o erro da melhor forma.

**Sintaxe**

A estruturação desses blocos obedece à seguinte sintaxe:

```
try {

// código que inclui comandos/invocações de métodos

// que podem gerar uma situação de exceção.

}

catch (XException ex) {

// bloco de tratamento associado à condição de

// exceção XException ou a qualquer uma de suas

// subclasses, identificada aqui pelo objeto

// com referência ex

}

catch (YException ey) {

// bloco de tratamento para a situação de exceção

// YException ou a qualquer uma de suas subclasses

}

finally {

// bloco de código que sempre será executado após

// o bloco try, independentemente de sua conclusão

// ter ocorrido normalmente ou ter sido interrompida

}
```

Onde `XException` e `YException` deveriam ser substituídos pelo nome do tipo de exceção. Os blocos não podem ser separados por outros comandos — um erro de sintaxe seria detectado pelo compilador Java neste caso. Cada bloco try pode ser seguido por zero ou mais blocos catch, onde cada bloco catch refere-se a uma única exceção.

O bloco finally, quando presente, é sempre executado. Em geral, ele inclui comandos que liberam recursos que eventualmente possam ter sido alocados durante o processamento do bloco try e que podem ser liberados, independentemente de a execução ter encerrado com sucesso ou ter sido interrompida por uma condição de exceção. A presença desse bloco é opcional.

Fonte : http://www.devmedia.com.br/blocos-try-catch/7339.

Comment: No php não tem checked exceptions, o problema é que nem tudo exception no php algumas funções retornam valor para indicar falha.

Answer (score 6):

Para simplificar, imagine que voce esteja fazendo algumas operações, por exemplo divisão.

```
var a  = b / c;
```

O que acontece caso C assuma o valor de 0?
O programa irá mostrar um erro de divisão por 0.

Erros deste tipo não podem ser 'comparados' em um IF. Por isto a utilização de TRY (tente em ingles)

```
TRY{ ///TENTE FAZER AS PROXIMAS OPERACOES
 ...operacoes
 }CATCH{ /// se houver algum erro/exception em '...operacoes' 
 ... o que fazer
 }
```

Neste caso:

```
try {
    double a=10;
    double b=0;
    double result=a/b; 
    System.out.println(result);
    System.out.println("inside-try");
} catch (Exception e) {

    System.out.println("division by zero exception");
    System.out.println("inside-catch");

}
```

Answer (score 6):

A melhor forma de entender a importância da utilização de blocos [`try{} catch{} finally{}`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.exceptions.php) é ter total ciência de uma verdade no mundo da programação:

- **Não existe nenhuma aplicação que não gere exceções**

E essas exceções podem ser geradas de suas formas: não-propositais e e propositais. As exceções não-propositais são geradas pelo sistema em forma de bugs, isto é, erros desconhecidos na aplicação. As exceções propositais são geradas pelo sistemas para tratamentos de erros esperados que podem gerar [`bugs`](https://www.techtudo.com.br/noticias/2019/01/o-que-e-bug-entenda-a-origem-da-palavra-e-conheca-exemplos.ghtml) caso não tratado, como por exemplo, tratativas de validações de parâmetros através da exceção [InvalidArgumentsException](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.invalidargumentexception.php).

Neste contexto porque utilizar exceções? Criar uma exceção ou qualquer outra coisa no código precisa precisa de algo muito importante chamado **NECESSIDADE**. Um bom exemplo que explica o que eu quero dizer é o uso desnecessário de `getters e setters` como sendo boas práticas. Desde quado criar algo em sua aplicação que nenhuma outra classe irá utilizar? Porque vou criar um bloco de exceções se não vou utilizar pra nada?

Neste sentido vou expor 4 situações que utilizo o bloco de exceções nas aplicações que crio atualmente.

1. Bloco de exceções nos [`Controller`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/329167/como-utilizar-o-controller-em-uma-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-java/329178#329178);
2. Manipulação do [`stack trace`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace);
3. Aplicação de regras de negócio quando uma exceção ocorre;
4. Monitoramento de exceções para logs.

**Bloco de exceções nos controller** - Os pontos positivos que vejo ao criar exceções no `controller`:

- Exibição primária do erro para o *front-end*: Imagine a seguinte hierarquia de classes. `Controller > Service_01 > Service_02 > Service_03`. A regra de negócio contida neste cenário é um bug (`throw Exception`) ocorrido na classe `Service_03`. Caso não tenha as necessidades dos itens 2 à 4. O uso do bloco de exceção no `Controller`  será ser o suficiente para todas as regras contidas nos `Services`. O erro primário irá chegar sem interferência de outros blocos de exceções podendo ser manipulado apenas no final, no momento de exibição ao usuário. Claro que uma trativa mais amigável deve ser realizada para o usuário.
- Tratativas para exceções amigáveis ao usuário: referente a esta abordagem a construção de blocos de exceção nos `controller` permitirá centralizar a regra numa classe do tipo `abstrat` estendendo para todas as `controller`. Neste cenário vc estará aplicando conceitos [OOP](https://medium.com/@TDamiao/16-conceitos-poo-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-orientada-a-objeto-6cdc72ac3ee2) de estado, abstração, encapsulamento, herança, dependencie, etc.., conceitos de [SOLID](https://medium.com/thiago-aragao/solid-princ%C3%ADpios-da-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-orientada-a-objetos-ba7e31d8fb25), como Princípio da Responsabilidade Única, isto é, somente os `controller` devem realizar as tratativas de exceções amigáveis.

**Manipulação do `stack trace`** - Transformar exceções que não servem para aplicação em exceção úteis. Por exemplo um erro de `ReflactionClass`. Eu sei que a classe `BuutonEnum` pode gerar exceção `Unhandled \ReflectionException` (*ReflectionException* não tratada). E isso só pode ocorrer se ela for chamada fora do contexto. Por isso no `catch{}` manipulo como a exceção deve ser gerada para chegar até o `Controller`.

```
abstract class ButtonEnum
{

    public static function all($class)
    {
        try {
            $reflector = new ReflectionClass($class);
        } catch (\ReflectionException $e) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Class is not a button type');
        }
        return $reflector->getConstants();
    }
}

class ButtonType2Enum
{
    const DEFAULT = 'default';
    const PRIMARY = 'primary';
    const DANGER = 'danger';

    public static function all()
    {
        return ButtonEnum::all(__CLASS__);
    }
}
```

**Aplicação de regras de negócio quando uma exceção ocorre** Quem nunca?

```
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        // do something
        DB::commit();
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        // do something
        DB::rollBack();
    }
```

O famoso exemplo de apenas persistir o código se tudo deu certo. Um caso mais complexo que tive o prazer de trabalhar foi relacionado a curadoria de dados. Os dados só eram aceitos pelo sistema se todo um *match* de validação de valores financeiros de despesas e receitas eram aceito.

**Monitoramento de exceções para logs**: Em funcionalidades extremamentes importantes de uma aplicação, como por exemplo, o fluxo de pagamento de qualquer página e-commerce é, na minha opinião, um ponto importante para monitoramento. Logo, o que acontece neste fluxo, quanto antes a equipe ficar sabendo será melhor. Imagine agora uma equipe de mais de 30 pessoas adicionando e removendo código. Por isso, ferramentas como *bugsnag* e *graylog* são colocados em `catch{}` para exceções que precisam ser monitorados.