# Uso específico do try-catch

Tags: java, hibernate, exceção, crud, try-catch

Estou estudando Hibernate e com ele vieram algumas dúvidas que já me vieram até antes mas não questionei a fundo.

```
public void salvar(Usuario usuario){
    Session sessao = null;
    Transaction transacao = null;

    try{
        sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
        sessao.save(usuario);
        transacao.commit();
    }catch(HibernateException e){
        System.out.println("Não foi possível inserir o usuário. Erro: "+e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        try{
            sessao.close();
        }catch(Throwable e){
            System.out.println("Não foi possível fechar operação de atualização. Messagem: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Do jeito que está me parece meio "sujo" digo, está superlotado de `try-catch` para todos os lugares, um código limpo é realmente assim?

Outra pergunta é, qual o emprego do uso de `try` com recurso? Eu devo usar sempre que possível o `try` *w/ resources*?

Comment: Essa resposta pode te ajudar [Para que servem os Blocos Try/Catch e quando devem ser utilizados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58536/para-que-servem-os-blocos-try-catch-e-quando-devem-ser-utilizados/424523#424523)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Uma situação peculiar

Esse exemplo que você deu é interessante porque uma `HibernateException`, que não é uma *checked exception* (isto é, exceção que deve ser tratada ou repassada para o nível acima) pode ser disparada por uma `SQLException` do JDBC, que é *checked*, que por sua vez pode ser disparada por uma `IOException`, que também é *checked*, e pode acontecer quando a conexão com o banco é perdida (após ter sido estabelecida, naturalmente). Porém o fato de `HibernateException` não ser *checked* desobriga o tratamento da exceção, o que pode ou não ser recomendável nessa situação, a conferir abaixo (e você verá que ela precisa ser tratada).

Quando a conexão cai algum dos métodos `beginTransaction()`, `save()` ou `commit()` irá lançar uma `HibernateException`, indicando que a conexão foi perdida e o recurso (socket aberto com o banco) precisa ser liberado. Ou, em outras palavras, sinalizando que `sessao.close()` precisa ser chamado. Porém `sessao.close()`, que por debaixo dos panos chama `Socket.close()`, além de liberar o socket (recurso do sistema) irá também disparar uma exceção ao tentar fechar a conexão que já foi perdida.

**Obs.:** De acordo com a documentação dos métodos `Session.close()` e `Session.disconnect()`, eles só precisam ser chamados em aplicações que passam uma conexão JDBC persistente (*long-session* ou *long-conversation*) ao Hibernate em vez de deixá-lo criar um *pool* delas sozinho. Se você usa um *pool* de conexões não chame `sessao.close()` e ignore o que eu falo sobre a segunda exceção.

### Segunda exceção: capture e depois ignore

Essa segunda exceção não precisa receber nenhum tratamento especial porque é um acontecimento normal decorrente da perda de conexão de rede. Então basta capturar essa segunda exceção e não fazer nada de mais com ela, nem mesmo logar. O socket será liberado e deixará de ser um recurso ocupado no sistema, o que [seria um potencial problema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385452/serversocket-is-it-really-necessary-to-close-it) caso o número de conexões abertas seja (ou possa ficar) muito grande. O sistema operacional é limitado no número de sockets que pode manter ocupados, mesmo que desconectados.

O único problema dessa segunda exceção, além de não precisar logar nada, é que o `catch (Throwable e)` deveria ser mais específico: `catch (HibernateException e)`.

### Primeira exceção: passe para o nível acima

Já o `catch` para a primeira exceção pode ou não ser necessário. Em geral nessa situação o nível acima irá querer tratar alguma exceção de falha no banco, talvez exibindo uma caixa de diálogo para o usuário ou de alguma outra forma, então em vez de capturar a `HibernateException` e simplesmente logar você tem a opção de deixar essa exceção ir para o nível acima diretamente ou então capturá-la e lançar em seu lugar uma exceção de mais "alto nível", que não especifique que se trata de uma exceção do Hibernate. Você pode achar que `HibernateException` é uma coisa específica de uma certa solução de persistência que seu sistema deve ser livre para trocar por outras, e que assim deve trocá-la por uma `DaoException` (DAOs fazem sentido em Hibernate? Acho que não muito né heheheh), ou `PersistenceException` ou algo do tipo (estou dando um exemplo qualquer aqui de exceção, somente para frisar essa ideia):

```
// Resolvi tornar checked também, mas isso é opcional
public class PersistenceException extends Exception {
    public PersistenceException(Throwable e) {
        super(e);
    }
}

public void salvar(Usuario usuario) throws PersistenceException {
    Session sessao = null;

    try {
        sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
        sessao.save(usuario);
        transacao.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        throw new PersistenceException(e);
    } finally {
        try{
            if (sessao != null) {
                sessao.close();
            }
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            // Não precisa fazer nada
        }
    }
}
```

### Conclusão

Nesse caso, você pode observar que mesmo `HibernateException` não sendo *checked* e você não sendo obrigado a tratar as duas exceções que foram geradas, é melhor tratá-las de alguma forma para evitar que um recurso do sistema seja deixado ocupado.

Sobre o *try with resources*, `Session` não implementa a interface `Closeable` então nesse caso não dá para usar.

Comment: Entendi! Então realmente preciso fechar a sessão, não tinha ideia sobre Session não implementar Closeable. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 8):

Não, você está coberto de razão, as pessoas capturam exceções muito mais do que devem. Ainda que Java exija ou pelo menos incentive que capture muitas exceções que não deveriam ser capturadas, ou pelo menos deveriam ser capturadas em outro momento. [Falo isto em todo lugar aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101%20%5Bexception%5D).

Acho pouco provável que o `try` mais interno seja necessário. Se acontecer de não conseguir fechar a conexão provavelmente está em uma condição tão catastrófica que isto é um erro de programação ou o ambiente está tão comprometido, que a melhor coisa a fazer é deixar a plicação quebrar. Até pode capturar a exceção em outro lugar para dar uma mensagem bonitinha e talvez *logar* o que aconteceu, mas deve ser um tratamento geral de toda a aplicação e não algo mais localizado e específico.

É quase certo que capturar `Exception` está errado, a não ser no `main()` ou algum lugar onde centraliza a execução da aplicação, onde seja o ponto de entrada e saída dela. Eu diria que capturar `Throwable` está sempre errado. Além de ser genérica demais (veja porque é ruim nas respostas do *link* acima), ela pega erros de programação ou que não podem ser feito nada. Estes erros não devem ser tratados, eles devem ser resolvidos.

O outro `try` pode ser útil. Claro que se for só para mostrar o erro no console e mais nada, não sei se é tão útil, pode até ser em algum caso, mas acho que este não é motivo da pergunta.

Capturar um erro onde um recurso externo está te informando de uma falha costuma ser uma coisa boa. Só precisa ver se o local é o melhor possível. Não precisa necessariamente capturar o mais rápido possível. E sim, muitas vezes é o caso, aí parece adequado.

Java 7 introduziu o [`try` para recursos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) onde o `finally` passa ser desnecessário. Se o Hibernate usa este padrão ele pode ser eliminado. Parece que não usa para este objeto, mas fica a dica para eliminar em outros casos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Mas neste caso o try para recursos não me daria um autocloseable ? Podendo passar para um catch mas sem necessidade de um finally?

Comment: @Kolnmrk você tem razão, dá para usar o `catch` com o `try()`. Corrigido. Hoje estou meio dorminhoco. Muita linguagem, cada uma com um jeito...

Comment: @bigown Confira no código da minha resposta, acredito que no caso de `sessao` a inicialização como null não é redundante porque `openSession()` pode lançar exceção antes de dar tempo de retornar a instância de `Session` e isso precisa ser checado no `sessao.close()`.

Comment: @Piovezan acho que tens razão

Answer (score 6):

Fechar recursos propriamente nem sempre é tão simples quanto parece. Problemas mais sutis podem ocorrer.

Estive lendo esse dias o artigo [*How to Close JDBC Resources Properly – Every Time*](http://blog.shinetech.com/2007/08/04/how-to-close-jdbc-resources-properly-every-time/). Para conexões normais, isto é, usando `Connection` e `Statement` e não Hibernate ou JPA, o código mais adequado é o seguinte:

```
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
try {
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    try {
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("some query");
        try {
            //recuperar resultado aqui
        } finally {
            resultSet.close();
        }
    } finally {
        statement.close();
    }
} finally {
    connection.close();
}
```

No seu caso, especificamente, você poderia fazer assim:

```
try {
    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
        Transaction transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
        try {
            sessao.save(usuario);
            transacao.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transacao.rollback();
            throw e;
        }
    } finally {
        sessao.close();
    }
} catch(Throwable e) {
    trataErro(e);
}
```

A desvantagem do código é o nível de aninhamento, pode ser confuso. A vantagem é que você não precisa ficar tratando valores desnecessariamente. Todas os recursos são fechados dentro do escopo e, pelo menos para mim, mais fácil de entender.

Entretanto, um erro comum em aplicações grandes é ficar usando código *boileroplate* em todo lugar. Depois algum programador novo esquece de algum `finally` e sua aplicação começa a ter vazamento de memória.

Uma forma de resolver isso usando acesso direto ao banco de dados é através de uma biblioteca como `JdbcTemplate` do Spring.

Para JPA ou Hibernate você pode configurar usar um framework de Inversão de Controle e Injeção de Dependências como o Spring para injetar a sua `Session` e gerenciar automaticamente o seu fechamento dentro do escopo de uma requisição (pensando num sistema web).

Ou, caso não possa ou não queira usar frameworks, você mesmo pode encapsular essa lógica. Exemplo usando Java 8 e lambdas:

```
public void salvar(Usuario usuario) {
    execute(session -> session.save(usuario));
}

public void execute(Consumer<Session> consumer) {
    try {
        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            Transaction transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
            try {
                consumer.accept(sessao);
                transacao.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                transacao.rollback();
                throw e;
            }
        } finally {
            sessao.close();
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        trataErro(e);
    }
}
```

Pronto, agora você nunca mais precisa repetir esse código.

**E depois, se você sentir necessidade de adicionar mais um `try/catch` para fazer um *rollback* em caso de erro, só precisa mexer em um lugar.**

Exemplo:

```
public void execute(Consumer<Session> consumer) {
    try {
        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            Transaction transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
            try {
                consumer.accept(sessao);
                transacao.commit();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                transacao.rollback(); 
                throw e;
            }
        } finally {
            sessao.close();
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        trataErro(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Não me ocorreu que ResultSets, Statements e Transactions podem ser fechados. Essa é certamente uma informação importante. Agora, eu discordo da inicialização direta da variável que mantém a conexão ou a sessão. Obter a conexão é uma operação de I/O e como tal pode gerar uma exceção, que precisaria ser capturada e tratada.

Comment: @Piovezan Na verdade isso foi um erro meu, transações não são fechadas, mas devem ter o commit ou rollback. Assim que chegar em casa eu arrumo isso.

Comment: Quando olhei o artigo achei que havia visto a transação ser fechada :)

Comment: No meu caso, cheguei a questionar o uso constante de try/catch, no entanto, além de trazer um código extensivo você veio com uma informação bastante valiosa sobre o uso de recursos. Parece complexo mas é bem tranquilo de entender, tentarei aplicar esse pattern nos meus projetos.

Comment: Pensando melhor, a inicialização direta não está errada se a intenção for repassar a exceção para o nível acima. Mas tem a restrição que comentei, você vai estar passando um detalhe de implementação (exceção de um framework específico) para a camada de cima, o que pode não ser desejável.

Comment: @Piovezan Eu também não gosto da inicialização direta, tanto que no meu exemplo final eu fiz um tratamento para evitar isso. Acho que o foco do artigo foi em tratar o `close` e não erros. Do meu ponto de vista a aplicação deve logar devidamente o erro e encapsular a exceção original numa resposta amigável.

Answer (score 3):

Sempre que voce quiser fazer o tratamento de um possível erro, voce vai ter que usar o try/catch. Se o erro que voce recebe do Hibernate, é suficiente pra você nas camadas acima, simplesmente não trate a exceção.

Dependendo das suas escolhas para a camada de apresentação, existem outras maneiras de tratar os erros de forma automatizada, como o Spring MVC (No caso de aplicações web) como explica este [artigo](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Quanto ao finally, acredito que as versões novas do hibernate tratam o fechamento de sessão, sem que voce tenha que se preocupar com isso.

Mas denovo, se voce tem interesse específico de tratar a possibilidade de não fechamento imediato da sessão, entao SIM, voce vai ter que fazer esse código "sujo" pra resolver seu problema.