# Onde devo colocar os blocos Try/Catch usando MVC?

Tags: java-ee, exceção, java, try-catch

estou fazendo uma aplicação web em java e tenho algumas duvidas em relação ao bloco try catch, estou usando o padrão MVC e tenho os seguintes códigos:

Controller:

```
try {
    String pesquisa = "%" + request.getParameter("pesquisa") + "%";
    List<Administrador> adm = serviceAdm.listarAdm(pesquisa);

    request.setAttribute("adm", adm);
    RequestDispatcher disp = request.getRequestDispatcher("administradores.jsp");
    disp.forward(request, response);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Erro: " + ex);
    request.setAttribute("erro", true);
    RequestDispatcher disp = request.getRequestDispatcher("principal.jsp");
    disp.forward(request, response);
}
```

Model:

```
public List<Administrador> listarAdm(String pesquisa) {
    try {
        return (List<Administrador>) admDB.selectAdms(pesquisa);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

E uso o DAO para fazer a conexão:

```
public List<Administrador> selectAdms(String pesquisa) {
    List<Administrador> usuarios = manager
            .createQuery("select a from Administrador a where nome LIKE :pesquisa")
            .setParameter("pesquisa", pesquisa).getResultList();

    return usuarios;
}
```

Gostaria de saber se caso der algum problema no Model, como eu coloquei para ele retornar `null`, ele não vai entrar no catch do `Controller`? Eu devo colocar o `try/catch` em todos os arquivos ou só nos `Controllers`?

Comment: Tenho duas perguntas para responder sua resposta : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58536/blocos-try-catch?rq=1 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108484/uso-espec%C3%ADfico-do-try-catch?rq=1

Comment: Foi você quem criou o seu proprio MVC? Ou é algum framework especifico?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ideia de uso do try catch é justamente capturar exceções que a aplicação possa lançar e executar uma operação alternativa. Então você deve colocar escopos de try catch toda vez que a aplicação puder lançar um erro, ou seja, se um erro pode ocorrer em um arquivo, use try catch.

Pelo seu código, o catch do controller lançará uma exceção por você tentar utilizar uma variável que está como null. Então, sua lógica funcionará corretamente.

Comment: *Downvoters*, poderiam explicar ao Jader (que está respondendo pela primeira vez no site), o motivo do voto negativo?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar throws na assinatura dos métodos do model para ecoar as exceptions direto para o Controller ao invés do try catch ou usar o try catch mesmo e dentro do catch você faz um throw new para especificar o erro gerado no model.