# try e catch com redirecionamento para outra página

Tags: php

Colegas.

Tenho o código abaixo:

```
try{
  if($param['usuario'] != '' and $param['senha'] != ''){
    return "<script>window.location.href='painel.php';</script>";
  }else{
    throw new Exception('Erro ao acessar');
  }
}catch(Exception $e){
   $erro = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Estou querendo colocar dessa forma, mas não sei se é o correto:

```
throw new Exception('<script>window.location.href='erro.php';</script>');
```

Sempre uso mensagens, mas gostaria de direcionar para outra página. Estou inseguro de usar a forma que passei, usando o direcionamento no Exception. Existe outro meio usando o try e catch ou posso usar dessa forma?

Comment: Não é mais fácil no `else` redirecionar com o `header()` ?

Comment: Olá rray. Sim, pensei nisso, mas o catch não é fundamental no caso de usarmos o try?

Comment: Nesse caso é melhor nem usar exception não faz mto sentido além de vc desviar o fluxo de proposito com `throw new Exception`. Tem algumas perguntas sobre em quais casos utilizar exceptions veja [nesse link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%c3%a7%c3%a3o?sort=votes&pageSize=30)

Comment: Certo. Vou tentar dessa forma. Obrigado rray.

Comment: Lembrando que a função header só funciona quando é a primeira saída para a página (antes de qualquer echo ou html, por exemplo), caso contrário o header não redirecionará a página.

Comment: Essa resposta pode te ajudar [Para que servem os Blocos Try/Catch e quando devem ser utilizados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58536/para-que-servem-os-blocos-try-catch-e-quando-devem-ser-utilizados/424523#424523)