# Cannot destroy the zip context

Tags: php, arquivo-zip

O que ocasiona esse erro?

Tenho um código onde eu crio um `Zip` através da classe `ZipArchive`.

Eu leio um determinado diretório e pego todos os arquivos de imagem presentes nele. Adiciono no ZIP e, no final, o usuário faz o download desse zip. Esse Zip é criado na pasta temporária padrão do SO.

O meu código é esse:

```
function getDownloadFotosZip($remessaID)
{
    $solicitacoes = Remessa::findOrFail($remessaID)->solicitacoes;

    $zip = new \ZipArchive();

    $zipName = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'remessa_');

    $remessaIDComZeros = zero_fill($remessaID, 4);

    if ($zip->open($zipName, ZipArchive::CREATE) === true) {

        $filesWithProblems = [];

        foreach ($solicitacoes as $solicitacao) {

            $filename = $solicitacao->foto_fullpath;

            $filenameInZip = "{$remessaIDComZeros}/{$solicitacao->codigo}.jpg";

            if ($filename && File::exists($filename)) {

                $zip->addFile($filename, $filenameInZip);

            } else {

                $filesWithProblems[] = $filename;

            }
        }

        if (($count = count($filesWithProblems)) > 0) {

            $errorMessage = "{$count} foto não foram encontrados no sistema:\n" . implode(PHP_EOL, $filesWithProblems);

            $zip->addFromString('erros.txt', $errorMessage);
        }

        $zip->close();

        return Response::download($zipName, "remessa_{$remessaIDComZeros}.zip");
    }


}
```

O seguinte erro está sendo gerado

> exception 'ErrorException' with message 'ProducaoController::getDownloadFotosRemessa(): Cannot destroy the zip context' in /var/www/newtonpaiva/app/controllers/ProducaoController.php:0

Está dando erro `Cannot destroy the zip context` na famosa linha `0`.

**Observação**: Estou usando o framework Laravel, porém não adicionarei tags, pois o problema é específico do `ZipArchive`, e não do Framework.

Qual é a solução para isso?

Comment: Conferiu se o diretório que está pegando o zipname está com permissão suficiente e o `remessa_` existe?

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade no PHP o `remessa_` que eu usei é para ele gerar um nome de um arquivo temporário com um prefixo. O arquivo é criado pela função `tempnam` automaticamente.

Comment: Tenta deixar já deixar criado o diretório sem utilizar a função, já tive um problema semelhante e o problema era a não localização dele.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade mas na verdade eu não crio o diretório. A função `sys_get_temp_dir` retorna o nome da pasta temporária do Sistema Operacional. Na verdade, está usando o `/tmp` no Linux, e essa pasta existe. Vou tentar dar permissão nessa pasta para ver se resolve o problema :D

Comment: Você está chamando `$zip->close()` dentro do `if ($zip->open(..)`, aproveita e tira o `return` de lá também. Essa deve ser a causa do erro. :)

Comment: @zekk filho, eu preciso do `return`. Senão, o Laravel não faz o Download.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Me expressei mal, coloque o `return` fora do contexto do `if`.. algo assim: http://pastebin.com/GceS8r4V

Comment: @zekk tem um try/catch englobando tudo. Eu tirei pra por na pergunta :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Legal :) Então use `try` para criar o *zip*, `catch` para tratar exceções e o `finally` para fechar a instância do *zip*. Dê uma olhada [nessa pergunta também](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58536/6454). Espero que ajude.

Comment: @zekk a questão é que o código estava funcionando perfeitamente antes. Não precisei mexer na lógica, a única coisa que eu fiz foi fazer um pull no servidor (talvez eu tenha que ver se é permissão)