# Boas práticas para utilização de blocs Try / Catch

Tags: c#, .net

Qual a melhor estratégia para utilizar os blocos Try / Catch:

```
try {
   //FAÇA ALGO
} 
catch(Exception ex){
  //LOGAR O ERRO
  //LANÇAR O ERRO PARA CIMA?
}
```

Exemplo:

Uma operação de calculo de imposto inicia o processo pela UI disparando um evento de um botão. Este evento irá chamar um método de aplicação onde irá tratar os dados e efetuar as devidas operações. Vamos supor que a transação como um todo só será satisfeita se todo o processo ocorrer bem, ou seja, persistência de dados na base, e operações comuns.

Se ocorrer uma exceção em um método que faz um cálculo antes da informação ser persistida ou uma exceção na persistência dos dados, o que se deve fazer?

- Lançar todas as exceções para cima logando-as em cada método interno e exibir o erro na tela?
- Como desfazer toda a transação caso a excessão aconteça em um ponto de execução da mesma?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Blocos Try/Catch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58536/blocos-try-catch)

Comment: Fechei como ampla pela amplitude de problemas nela :) Depende de muitos detalhes para tomar uma decisão, depende do estilo de cada. Talvez não seja o caso de lançar exceções. Desfazer transações dá pra escrever um livro.

Comment: @bigown poderia exemplificar um detalhe para melhorar a pergunta?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions