# É recomendável manipular regras com "try-catch"?

Tags: c#, exceção, estilo-de-codificação, try-catch, refatoração

Podemos manipular erros de várias formas, mas a que menos vai usar código e tempo do programador é o `try`, presente em quase todas linguagens orientadas a objetos. Mas, quando deve ser usado o `try`, independente da linguagem?

Considere o código de C# abaixo:

```
string SenhaNumerica = Console.ReadLine(); // obtém a senha que o usuário digitar
Autenticador x = new Autenticador();
// Suponha que a classe Autenticador só irá aceitar a senha se ela seguir
// estas regras:
//  - Deve ser numérica
//  - Deve ter mais de cinco caracteres
//  - Não deve começar com número abaixo de 4
//  - Deve ter algum caractere especial
// Caso não siga essas regras, é atirado uma exceção no runtime.
```

Como descrito no comentário acima, a classe `Autenticador` irá **atirar uma exceção se a senha não seguir os conformes.**

Esse foi o início do código. Agora vem a prática, qual dessas abaixo seria a prática correta para manipular esta senha?

```
// PRÁTICA DE CONDIÇÕES
// - "Deve ser numérica"
int tmp_variavel;
if(int.TryParse(SenhaNumerica, out tmp_variavel) == false) {
    Console.WriteLine("A senha não é numérica");
    return;
}
// - "Deve ter mais de cinco caracteres"
if(SenhaNumerica.Length <= 5) {
    Console.WriteLine("Senha não numérica.");
    return;
}
// - "Não deve começar com número abaixo de 4"
if(Convert.ToInt32(SenhaNumerica.Substring(0, 1)) < 4) {
    Console.WriteLine("Não pode começar com número abaixo de 4.");
    return;
}
// Deve ter algum caractere especial
if(SenhaNumerica.Any(ch => !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch) == false) {
    Console.WriteLine("Não foi encontrado nenhum caractere especial");
    return;
}
// Enfim, com certeza que todas regras foram obedecidas, passa
// a senha para o Autenticador
Autenticador.Senha = SenhaNumerica;
// OK!
```

Mas, todo esse código enorme acima pode ser encurtado com um simples bloco:

```
try {
    Autenticador.Senha = SenhaNumerica;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("Senha não segue regras.");
    return;
}
```

Não entendo quando usar o `try` e porquê usá-lo. Sendo que há várias maneiras de contorná-lo, mesmo assim, é recomendável usar o bloco `try` em vez de criar condições?

> A *tag* "C#" foi colocada para colorir o código.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exceção nada tem a ver com linguagem orientada a objeto, estes conceitos são completamente ortogonais. Existe linguagem dita OO que não tem exceção e linguagem não OO que tem exceção.

Há escolas, ou seja, um monte de gente que tem uma opinião, sobre como deve usar. Cada linguagem tende a recomendar mais uma coisa ou outra.

Linguagens mais modernas tendem a evitar o uso de exceções. É verdade que elas não se tornaram *mainstream*, porém é mais por questões mercadológicas. Do ponto de vista de engenharia já se considera um erro ter exceção na linguagem, principalmente da forma como elas são implementadas.

C# começou adotando a postura do Java e abusando de exceções, logo entenderam que havia vários casos onde não fazia sentido ter exceções e começaram criar [mecanismos melhores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101). Eu tenho uma [resposta que fala como o uso de exceções geralmente é errado em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101) na maior parte dos casos.

Note que a origem das exceções do C# tem até a ver com o C++ e nesta linguagem é comum que equipes proíbam o uso de exceções.

Um dos motivos para não abusar de exceções é [performance ruim delas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5888/101), especialmente em C#.

Se a situação é excepcional, ou seja, quase nunca acontece, ou se acontece é erro de programação e só ocorrerá em testes ou em produção por um lapso do programador, tudo bem. Se está acessando um recurso externo ou que o programador tem pouco controle e que ele pode falhar, faz sentido ter uma exceção. Se o que espera é o erro não é situação excepcional. Entradas de dados espera-se que venha errado, não é uma exceção vir errado.

[Usar exceções para controle de fluxo é errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101).

Neste exemplo tudo aquilo pode ser substituído por:

```
if (Autenticacao.Validador(senhaNumerica)) {
    return (Autenticador.Senha = true);
} else {
    WriteLine("Senha não segue regras.");
    return false; //indica que não autenticou
}
```

Tem outras formas de fazer isso sem exceção, mecanismos melhores não faltam.

Obviamente que se uma exceção é lançada todas as validações foram feitas dentro da classe. Então as faça e retorne um erro, só não lance a exceção. O erro aí no código de cima é tentar fazer o que a classe já faz para você.

Um exemplo usando exceção de uma forma que ninguém usa e é válida, embora eu não acho adequado fazê-lo (as pessoas não usam porque é inadequado, é porque não sabem como fazê-lo), mais como curiosidade:

```
if (Autenticacao.Validador(senhaNumerica) is SenhaException excessao) {
    Autenticador.Senha = true;
    return true;
} else {
    WriteLine($"Senha não segue regras. Motivo: {excessao.Message}. Veja o erro\n{excecao.StackTrace()}");
    return false;
}

public SenhaException Validador(string senha) {
    if (!int.TryParse(SenhaNumerica, out var senhaConvertida)) return new SenhaException("A senha não é numérica");
    if (senha.Length <= 5) return new SenhaException("Senha não numérica.");
    if (senhaConvertida[0]) < 4) return new SenhaException("Não pode começar com número abaixo de 4.");
    if (!senha.Any(ch => !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch)) return new SenhaException("Não foi encontrado nenhum caractere especial");
}
```

Obviamente que precisaria criar a `SenhaException` provavelmente herdada de [`ApplicationException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.systemexception?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Claro que pode ser que você não tenha controle sobre a classe, não possa consertar o seu erro de arquitetura. Aí capture a exceção. Este tipo de exceção é o que o [Eric Lippert chama de ruído (*vexing*)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.applicationexception?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0), então por decisão errada de alguém você é obrigado fazer isto.

Só não vá [capturar `Exception` que é errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101). Em geral o programador faz isso por desconhecimento e preguiça, principalmente o último, porque vários programadores aqui mesmo leem que não deve fazer isto e continua fazendo. Exceção talvez tenha sido o pior mecanismo criado na programação e certamente o mais abusado.

Deixar o código consumidor tratar os erros é um erro conceitual e um [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101). É a classe deste objeto que deveria estabelecer as regras do que é bom ou ruim, não o consumidor. A não ser que seja uma regra transitória e só faça sentido usar ali, o que não parece ser o caso. E se for, o segundo código não faz sentido.

Note que o segundo código, que trata exceção não é equivalente ao primeiro já que ele não trata cada tipo de erro separadamente. Com exceção para ser equivalente seria assim:

```
var erros = Autenticacao.Validador(senhaNumerica);
if (erros.Count == 0) return (Autenticador.Senha = true);
foreach (var erro in erros) WriteLine(erro.Message);
return (Autenticador.Senha = false);
```

Se quiser tratar algum erro de forma específica é possível filtrar com o objeto de erro que tem em cada elemento da lista.

Talvez nem precise das mensagens de texto, isso poderia vir dentro da própria exceção, pra mim as mensagens aí também é um erro na maioria dos casos, mas não em todos.

Inclusive este código tem problemas. Acho estranho um `return` solto sem valor, os comentários demonstram que deveria ter um método ali, mistura regra de negócio com apresentação para o usuário.

Tem outro problema, só uma exceção será lançada. Para indicar os 4 erros aí teria que criar uma única exceção e internalizar nela os 4 problemas e tratar com `if` cada um, a lógica é até mais complexa, Entendeu como não tem como escapar de várias verificações?

Se o original só lança um `Exception` é o erro de engenharia extremo, essa informação não é útil, o principal motivo da exceção ser criada é ter uma informação mais rica acerca do erro. No *link* acima que falo de códigos de erro mostro que tem mecanismo melhores para transportar informações ricas sobre o erro.

Perceba que o código mostrado capturando exceção mostrará que a senha não segue as regras mesmo que o erro seja de memória, mesmo que seja um erro de programação, ou alguma outra coisa não prevista, por exemplo de banco de dados (vai que um dia o validador precisa acessar o banco de dados). Por isso que muitos programas são o caos, porque "param do dia para a noite", as pessoas programam para funcionar, não para ser o certo. O que funciona um dia não funciona no outro.

Obviamente que para o código que não tem exceção fazer o mesmo também precisa de 4 `if`s. E o método validador precisaria devolver um objeto que tenha as 4 invalidades. Algo assim:

```
public List<ValidationError> Validador(string senha) {
    var erros = new List<ValidationError>();
    if (!int.TryParse(SenhaNumerica, out var senhaConvertida)) erros.Add(new ValidationError(SenhaNaoNumerica, "A senha não é numérica"));
    if (senha.Length <= 5) erros.Add(new ValidationError(SenhaMuitoPequena, "Senha não numérica."));
    if (senhaConvertida[0]) < 4) erros.Add(new ValidationError(SenhaInicioAbaixoDe4, "Não pode começar com número abaixo de 4."));
    if (!senha.Any(ch => !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch)) erros.Add(new ValidationError(SenhaSemCaractereEspecial, "Não foi encontrado nenhum caractere especial"));
    return erros;
}
```

Obviamente teria que criar uma estrutura para `ValidationError` que provavelmente teria esses dois campos (se precisar mais coisas talvez precisa de uma classe, que eu evitaria quase a todo custo), um campo para segurar um objeto que indique o erro de forma canônica e outro com a mensagem. É como uma exceção mas de forma muito leve. Também poderia ser útil um tipo que carregue todos os erros de forma mais abstrata que uma lista dele. Por fim teria que criar esses objetos marcadores de indicação do que é o erro. Poderia ser uma enumeração, mas objetos isolados é mais orientado objeto.

Agora pode consumir mais ou menos assim:

```
var 
    Autenticador.Senha = SenhaNumerica;
} catch (SenhaNaoNumericaException) {
    Console.WriteLine("A senha não é numérica");
} catch (SenhaMuitoPequenaException) {
    Console.WriteLine("Senha não numérica.");
} catch (SenhaInicioAbaixoDe4Exception) {
    Console.WriteLine("Não pode começar com número abaixo de 4.");
} catch (SenhaSemCaractereEspecialException) {
    Console.WriteLine("Não foi encontrado nenhum caractere especial");
}
```

Estes códigos são simplificados e ingênuos. Em um sistema real eu daria muito mais atenção a como fazer. Na verdade teria tanto reaproveitamento que nem daria trabalho. Noto que boa parte dos programadores repetem muito esforço de desenvolvimento, alguns chegam fazer 20 vezes mais do que poderia se buscasse o caminho correto.

A pergunta demonstra uma dicotomia que não existe, está apresentando códigos que fazem coisas muito distintas, eles não podem ser comparados.

Mesmo o código original poderia ser melhor escrito, por exemplo:

```
if (!int.TryParse(senhaNumerica, out var senhaValida)) WriteLine("A senha não é numérica");
```

[Também coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/ManyWays.cs).

Note que nem as nomenclaturas são boas para os padrões do C#.

Um coisa que eu noto aqui no SOpt é que os programadores não criam suas exceções. É um misto de preguiça com desconhecimento. Se ele não cria exceção porque não entende, deveria ficar longe delas em tudo. Se acha muito trabalhoso, deveria evitá-las também e adotar outras soluções, deveria para de capturar onde não precisa. Noto que a maioria dos códigos poderiam ser menores, mais simples, mais legíveis, mais robustos, mais performáticos e mais depuráveis. Se os programadores gastassem algumas hora para aprender sobre exceções da forma correta economizaria muitas horas no desenvolvimento.

Outro detalhe que mostro acima como dá muito mais trabalho programar orientado a objeto e a maioria dos programadores inexperientes (qualitativamente) que dizem programar ou querer programar OO não tem paciência para lidar com esse esse trabalho a mais. Não vou entrar no mérito se compensa ou não ter esse trabalho a mais, depende do caso. Da maneira como a maioria programa, não compensa.

Enfim, dá para escrever muito mais, mas dá um capítulo de um livro, talvez um livro só sobre exceções.

Comment: Toda vez que se captura `Exception` uma fada morre e um dogge entra em agonia

Comment: Essa resposta pode te ajudar [Para que servem os Blocos Try/Catch e quando devem ser utilizados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58536/para-que-servem-os-blocos-try-catch-e-quando-devem-ser-utilizados/424523#424523)