# Quando usar exceções com ou como regras de negócio?

Tags: java, validação, exceção, engenharia-de-software, regra-de-negócio

Não sei como seria um título legal para essa pergunta, quem quiser pode melhorar.

A minha dúvida é, quando devo adotar, isto é, quais os critérios, para se adotar uma exceção personalizada (no caso do Java, uma subclasse de `RuntimeException` ou de `Exception`) para ser usada com/como regra de negócio?

Dessas do tipo `SaldoNegativoException`, `CpfInvalidoException`, `ProblemaNoSensorException`, `ProblemaNaCamadaTalException`, `SistemaInconsistenteException`, etc.

Não sei bolar bons nomes porque considero que não deve ser habitual criar esse tipo de exceção personalizada, quase nunca é uma boa ideia, então não estou habituado a usar.

Já devo ter usado (não lembro, ou melhor, não assumo :D) no máximo uma `DeveFecharConexaoException`, que teria achado péssima, pois não especifica a origem do problema como eu acho que deveria especificar (o que seria mais coeso em termos do nome da classe e da abstração que ela representa), e sim o que deve ser feito com relação ao mesmo (o que a meu ver não cabe fazer porque a exceção não deveria conter em si mesma a forma como ela deve ser tratada, isso deveria ser especificado pelo código de tratamento na camada correta de acordo com o tipo de exceção).

Ainda sobre validação, `ValidationException` faz sentido? Se sim, por quê, e qual a diferença em relação aos demais exemplos?

Coloquei a *tag* [java](/questions/tagged/java), mas talvez nem precise.

Comment: È bem simples, não use, isso é um absurdo, inclusive a própria linguagem, como outras, já passaram mudar essa ideia de centrar em exceções que é um mecanismo ruim: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17632/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88831/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243107/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/483290/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101

Comment: A resposta então é evitar usar de maneira geral, salvo (***ahem***) raríssimas exceções que até seria difícil imaginar quais seriam? Ou mesmo nunca?