# Try/Catch PDOException não funciona quando ocorre erro

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, exceção

Criei o seguinte método para executar as minhas querys:

```
public function setQuery($query) {
    try {
        $stmt = self::$conn->prepare($this->limpaQuery($query));
        return $stmt->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $Exception) {
        var_export($query);
        die();
    }
}
```

Funciona perfeitamente, mas quando executo uma query errada apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column...

O que eu não entendo é o porque ele não pega a PDOException, eu queria que toda query que não executasse fosse exibida.

**Updade**

```
/**
 * Conexao
 */
public function openConection() {
    try {

        //Verifica se uma instancia já existe
        if (!isset(self::$conn)) {
            //String de conexão
            self::$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->servername;dbname=$this->banco", $this->username, $this->password);

            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            self::$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }

        //Mensagem de status
        $this->status = "Conectado no host $this->servername, no banco dbname=$this->banco com o usuário $this->username";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        //Mensagem de status
        $this->status = "Falha ao tentar conectar: \n" . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tem certeza que a exceção é disparada neste método?

Comment: Sim, ele fala exatamente esta linha, e coloquei o try catch em todos os métodos que executam querys.

Comment: Essa resposta pode te ajudar [Para que servem os Blocos Try/Catch e quando devem ser utilizados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58536/para-que-servem-os-blocos-try-catch-e-quando-devem-ser-utilizados/424523#424523)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encontrei o problema, ele estava interpretando o PDOException como conexao\PDOException por causa do namespace.

```
namespace conexao;
```

Então eu importei o PDOException.

```
use PDOException;
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826052/pdo-catch-pdoexception-error

Comment: Bem que eu ia pedir isso nos comentários, mas não lembrava se dava erro de classe não definida ao utilizar no *catch*.

Comment: O estranho foi isso, ele não deu erro de classe não definida @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Eu tive o mesmo problema. Passei a implementar namespace nas classes e o PDOExecption deixou de funcionar como esperado.

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa setar a configuração *PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE* para *PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION*.

```
$conn = new PDO($host, $usuario, $senha);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, $conn::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Já esta assim :/

Comment: Então adicione também `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);`

Comment: Deu o mesmo efeito

Comment: Estranho porque eu testei aqui e funciona.

Comment: Eu postei a resposta, era por causa do namespace.

Comment: Salvei até como favorito, quem save um dia aconteça ai já sei aonde encontrar. :)

Answer (score 1):

Uma contrabarra antes do PDOxception resolveria seu problema, colocando a contrabarra, ele "quebra" seu namespace e não interpreta mais como "conexao\PDOxception".

```
public function setQuery($query) {
    try {
        $stmt = self::$conn->prepare($this->limpaQuery($query));
        return $stmt->execute();
    } catch (\PDOException $Exception) {
        var_export($query);
        die();
    }
}
```