# Como usar try, catch, finally e exception em php

Tags: php, try-catch

Estou com fonte onde preciso agora adapta-lo para usar o `try`, `catch`, `finally` e `exception` e não estou conseguindo, esse fonte já tem alguns `try´s` com `catch(PDOException $erro)` onde faço algumas validações, pois estou fazendo uma chamada com retorno `JSon` e retornando o status da operação para o usuário e creio que, agora, serão desnecessários.
Tentei isolar as mensagens para joga-las na exceção eliminando as mesmas do corpo do código, mas como disse sem sucesso, não sei exatamente o que tem que ser feito, pois tenho várias interações entre `select`, `delete` e `insert` para somente enviar o `commit` ou `rollBack` e enviar mensagem para o usuário, finalizando o processo.

O que tenho até agora:

A chamada:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function () {
        // Validation
        $("#frmGravaDados").validate({
            // Do not change code below
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {

                var data = $(form).serialize();

                console.log(data);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ajax/pInterfaceServico.php',
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#msgBusca").html('×AVISO! Enviando...');
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.codigo == "1") {
                            $("#msgBusca").html('×AVISO!' + response.mensagem  + '');                          

                        } else {
                            $("#msgBusca").html('×ATENÇÃO! ' + response.mensagem + '');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        console.log(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
                        $("#msgInsert").html('×ATENÇÃO! Ocorreu um erro no registro de direito. Contate o suporte técnico.');
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

O código no `php`:

```
// ATRIBUI UMA CONEXÃO PDO   
$conexao = Conexao::getInstance();
$crud    = Crud::getInstance($conexao);

// DADOS DO FORMULÁRIO
$IdInterface = (isset($_POST['IdInterface'])) ? $_POST['IdInterface'] : '';
$IdUsuario = (isset($_POST['IdUsuario'])) ? $_POST['IdUsuario'] : '';
$Servicos = (isset($_POST['Servicos'])) ? $_POST['Servicos'] : '';

try {
    // BUSCANDO REGISTROS USUÁRIO X SERVIÇO
    $sql = "SELECT 
              `gasServico`.IdServico,
              `gasUsuarioServico`.IdUsuario
            FROM
              `gasServico`
              INNER JOIN `gasUsuarioServico` ON (`gasServico`.IdServico = `gasUsuarioServico`.IdServico)
            WHERE
              (`gasUsuarioServico`.IdServico = `gasServico`.IdServico) AND 
              (`gasUsuarioServico`.IdUsuario = ?) AND 
              (`gasServico`.IdInterface = ?)";
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    // DEFINE O TIPO DA VARIÁVEL PDO::PARAM_INT OU STR
    $stm->bindValue(1, $IdUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->bindValue(2, $IdInterface, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->execute();
    $ResDados = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
    // CONTAGEM DE REGISTROS RETORNADOS
    $conProd = count($ResDados);  
    // FECHANDO A CONSULTA
    $stm->closeCursor();  

    // DELETANDO REGISTROS USUÁRIO X SERVIÇO
    foreach ($ResDados as $DadosUsuarioServico) { 
        try{            

            $IdUsuario = $DadosUsuarioServico->IdUsuario;
            $IdServico = $DadosUsuarioServico->IdServico;

            $sql = "DELETE FROM `gasUsuarioServico` WHERE `IdUsuario` = ? AND `IdServico` = ?";
            $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
            $stm->bindValue(1, $IdUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->bindValue(2, $IdServico, PDO::PARAM_INT);                    
            $stm->execute();                
            $retorno = array('codigo' => '1', 'mensagem' => ' Serviços excluídos com sucesso'); 
        } catch(PDOException $erro) {  
            $erro = $erro->getMessage();
            $retorno = array('codigo' => '0', 'mensagem' => ' Erro ao deletar os serviços. Tente novamente. ::$erro');
        }       
    }

    // GRAVANDO OS CHECKS MARCADOS
    if ($Servicos != "") {  
        try {   
            foreach($Servicos as $IdServico) {  
                // INSERT
                $crud = $conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO gasUsuarioServico (IdUsuario, IdServico) VALUES (?, ?)");
                $crud->bindParam(1, $IdUsuario , PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $crud->bindParam(2, $IdServico , PDO::PARAM_INT);       
                $crud->execute();       
                $retorno = array('codigo' => '1', 'mensagem' => ' Serviços inseridos com sucesso'); 
            }       
        } catch(PDOException $erro) {  
                $erro = $erro->getMessage();
                $retorno = array('codigo' => '0', 'mensagem' => ' Erro ao inserir os serviços. Tente novamente. ::$erro');
        }
    }

    // BUSCANDO REGISTROS USUÁRIO X SERVIÇO
    $sqlInterface = "    
        SELECT 
              gasUsuarioServico.IdUsuario,
              gasUsuarioServico.IdServico,
              gasServico.IdInterface
            FROM
              gasUsuarioServico
              INNER JOIN gasServico ON (gasUsuarioServico.IdServico = gasServico.IdServico)
            WHERE
              (gasUsuarioServico.IdUsuario = ?) AND 
              (gasServico.IdInterface = ?)";
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($sqlInterface);
    // DEFINE O TIPO DA VARIÁVEL PDO::PARAM_INT OU STR
    $stm->bindValue(1, $IdUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->bindValue(2, $IdInterface, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->execute();    
    $ResDadosInterface = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
    // CONTAGEM DE REGISTROS RETORNADOS
    $conSqlDel = count($ResDadosInterface); 
    // FECHANDO A CONSULTA
    $stm->closeCursor();  

    // DELETANDO REGISTROS USUÁRIO X INTERFACE
    if ($conSqlDel == 0) {
        try {
                $sql = "DELETE FROM gasUsuarioInterface WHERE gasUsuarioInterface.IdUsuario = ? AND gasUsuarioInterface.IdInterface = ?";
                $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);        
                $stm->bindValue(1, $IdUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stm->bindValue(2, $IdInterface, PDO::PARAM_INT);                    
                $stm->execute(); 
                $retorno = array('codigo' => '1', 'mensagem' => ' Interfaces do usuários deletadas com sucesso');
        } catch(PDOException $erro) {  
                $erro = $erro->getMessage();
                $retorno = array('codigo' => '0', 'mensagem' => ' Erro ao deletar interfaces para o usuário. Tente novamente. ::$erro');
        }   
    } else {

        // BUSCANDO REGISTROS INTERFACES
        $sqlInterfaceReg = "    
                SELECT * FROM
                    gasUsuarioInterface
                WHERE
                    (gasUsuarioInterface.IdUsuario = ?) AND 
                    (gasUsuarioInterface.IdInterface = ?)";
            $stm = $conexao->prepare($sqlInterfaceReg);
            // DEFINE O TIPO DA VARIÁVEL PDO::PARAM_INT OU STR
            $stm->bindValue(1, $IdUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->bindValue(2, $IdInterface, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->execute();        
            $ResUsuarioInterface = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
            $countInsert = count($ResUsuarioInterface);
            // FECHANDO A CONSULTA
            $stm->closeCursor();    

        if ($countInsert == 0) {
            try {
                // INSERT USUÁRIO X INTERFACE           
                $crud = $conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO gasUsuarioInterface (IdUsuario, IdInterface) VALUES (?, ?)");
                $crud->bindParam(1, $IdUsuario , PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $crud->bindParam(2, $IdInterface , PDO::PARAM_INT);     
                $crud->execute();       
                $retorno = array('codigo' => '1', 'mensagem' => ' Interfaces do usuários inseridas com sucesso');
            } catch(PDOException $erro) {  
                $erro = $erro->getMessage();
                $retorno = array('codigo' => '0', 'mensagem' => ' Erro ao deletar interfaces para o usuário. Tente novamente. ::$erro');
            }           
        }
    }   
} catch (Exception $e) { 
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

// FECHA CONEXÃO
$conexao = null;        

// RETORNO DE MENSAGEM
echo json_encode($retorno);
exit();
```

Comment: Essa resposta pode te ajudar [Para que servem os Blocos Try/Catch e quando devem ser utilizados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58536/para-que-servem-os-blocos-try-catch-e-quando-devem-ser-utilizados/424523#424523)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A estrutura do `try`, `catch` `finaly` é bem simples.

Dentro do `try` você coloca o código que tem risco de gerar exceções.

Você pode ter um ou mais `catch`, caso queira criar tratamentos diferentes para diferentes tipos de `exception`. No seu caso você esta criando um tratamento especial quando for o erro for gerado no **PDO** `PDOException`.

E no `finally` o que vai ser executado apenas se o que estava contido no `try` for executado sem gerar `exceptions`.

```
    try {
        //código que deseja ser executado
    } catch (PDOException $erro) {
        echo '$erro->getMessage();';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo '$e->getMessage();';
    } finally {
        //o que deseja que seja executado apenas se ocorreu tudo bem dentro do         try
    }
    //qualquer coisa que deseja executar após o try catch
```

Por exemplo, caso você deseje salvar em banco um usuário, e após ele estar salvo no banco deseja vincula-lo a outras tabelas.

Dentro do `try` você coloca a pare onde salva o usuário, e no `finally` chama os métodos que irão executar as outras operações.

Comment: Fiz um teste no código do PHP e constatei que Exception deve ser o ultimo nivel das Exceptions. Ou seja, PDOException deve ser um catch anterior ao catch da Exception;

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ee7c5dbb86ff324fcc145ce1f64f4660b76711c9

Comment: @Don'tPanic alterei o exemplo, valeu. Eu adicionei a observação sobre poder ter um ou mais, mas esse detalhe passou batido

Comment: Um detalhe sobre o finally: se o que estiver dentro do TRY ou do CATCH for encerrar o contexto, o finally é acionado anteriormente. por exemplo, se ao invés de "echo"s tivessem "return"s, somente o return do finally seria acionado. Pode testar! PHP 5.5+

Answer (score 2):

Depois de algumas pesquisas e ajuda de alguns amigos consegui o que estava precisando e venho compartilhar com vocês o resultado final, espero que possa ajudar a alguém.

Código comentado, segue:

```
// ATRIBUI UMA CONEXÃO PDO   
$conexao = Conexao::getInstance();
$crud    = Crud::getInstance($conexao);

// DADOS DO FORMULÁRIO
$IdInterface = (isset($_POST['IdInterface'])) ? $_POST['IdInterface'] : '';
$IdUsuario = (isset($_POST['IdUsuario'])) ? $_POST['IdUsuario'] : '';
$Servicos = (isset($_POST['Servicos'])) ? $_POST['Servicos'] : '';

try {

    // INICIALIZA A TRANSAÇÃO
    $conexao->beginTransaction();

    // BUSCANDO REGISTROS USUÁRIO X SERVIÇO
    $sql = "SELECT 
              `gasServico`.IdServico,
              `gasUsuarioServico`.IdUsuario
            FROM
              `gasServico`
              INNER JOIN `gasUsuarioServico` ON (`gasServico`.IdServico = `gasUsuarioServico`.IdServico)
            WHERE
              (`gasUsuarioServico`.IdServico = `gasServico`.IdServico) AND 
              (`gasUsuarioServico`.IdUsuario = ?) AND 
              (`gasServico`.IdInterface = ?)";
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    // DEFINE O TIPO DA VARIÁVEL INT OU STR
    $stm->bindValue(1, $IdUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->bindValue(2, $IdInterface, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->execute();
    $ResDados = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
    // CONTAGEM DE REGISTROS RETORNADOS
    $conProd = count($ResDados);  
    // FECHANDO A CONSULTA
    $stm->closeCursor();  

    // DELETANDO REGISTROS USUÁRIO X SERVIÇO
    foreach ($ResDados as $DadosUsuarioServico) { 
        try{

            $IdUsuario = $DadosUsuarioServico->IdUsuario;
            $IdServico = $DadosUsuarioServico->IdServico;

            $sql = "DELETE FROM `gasUsuarioServico` WHERE `IdUsuario` = ? AND `IdServico` = ?";
            $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
            $stm->bindValue(1, $IdUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->bindValue(2, $IdServico, PDO::PARAM_INT);                    
            $stm->execute(); 

        } catch(PDOException $erro) { 

            // DESFAZ TRANSAÇÃO ATUAL           
            $conexao->rollBack();           
            $erro = $erro->getMessage();
            $retorno = array('codigo' => '0', 'mensagem' => ' Erro ao deletar os serviços. Tente novamente [1]. ::$erro');  
            $conexao = null;        

            // RETORNO DE MENSAGEM
            echo json_encode($retorno);
            exit(); 

        }       
    }

    // GRAVANDO OS CHECKS MARCADOS
    if ($Servicos != "") {  
        try {   

            foreach($Servicos as $IdServico) {  
                // INSERT
                $crud = $conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO gasUsuarioServico (IdUsuario, IdServico) VALUES (?, ?)");
                $crud->bindParam(1, $IdUsuario , PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $crud->bindParam(2, $IdServico , PDO::PARAM_INT);       
                $crud->execute();                       
            }       

        } catch(PDOException $erro) {  

                // DESFAZ TRANSAÇÃO ATUAL
                $conexao->rollBack();           
                $erro = $erro->getMessage();
                $retorno = array('codigo' => '0', 'mensagem' => ' Erro ao inserir os serviços. Tente novamente [2]. ::$erro');
                $conexao = null;        

                // RETORNO DE MENSAGEM
                echo json_encode($retorno);
                exit();             

        }
    }

    // BUSCANDO REGISTROS USUÁRIO X SERVIÇO
    $sqlInterface = "SELECT 
                      gasUsuarioServico.IdUsuario,
                      gasUsuarioServico.IdServico,
                      gasServico.IdInterface
                    FROM
                      gasUsuarioServico
                      INNER JOIN gasServico ON (gasUsuarioServico.IdServico = gasServico.IdServico)
                    WHERE
                      (gasUsuarioServico.IdUsuario = ?) AND 
                      (gasServico.IdInterface = ?)";
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($sqlInterface);
    // DEFINE O TIPO DA VARIÁVEL INT OU STR
    $stm->bindValue(1, $IdUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->bindValue(2, $IdInterface, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->execute();    
    $ResDadosInterface = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
    // CONTAGEM DE REGISTROS RETORNADOS
    $conSqlDel = count($ResDadosInterface); 
    // FECHANDO A CONSULTA
    $stm->closeCursor();  

    // DELETANDO REGISTROS USUÁRIO X INTERFACE SE EXISTI SOBRAS
    if ($conSqlDel == 0) {
        try {

            $sql = "DELETE FROM gasUsuarioInterface WHERE gasUsuarioInterface.IdUsuario = ? AND gasUsuarioInterface.IdInterface = ?";
            $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);        
            $stm->bindValue(1, $IdUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->bindValue(2, $IdInterface, PDO::PARAM_INT);                    
            $stm->execute();            

        } catch(PDOException $erro) {  

            // DESFAZ TRANSAÇÃO ATUAL
            $conexao->rollBack();
            $erro = $erro->getMessage();
            $retorno = array('codigo' => '0', 'mensagem' => ' Erro ao deletar interfaces para o usuário. Tente novamente [3]. ::$erro');
            $conexao = null;        

            // RETORNO DE MENSAGEM
            echo json_encode($retorno);
            exit();             

        }   
    } else {

        // BUSCANDO REGISTROS INTERFACES
        $sqlInterfaceReg = "    
                SELECT * FROM
                    gasUsuarioInterface
                WHERE
                    (gasUsuarioInterface.IdUsuario = ?) AND 
                    (gasUsuarioInterface.IdInterface = ?)";
            $stm = $conexao->prepare($sqlInterfaceReg);
            // DEFINE O TIPO DA VARIÁVEL INT OU STR
            $stm->bindValue(1, $IdUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->bindValue(2, $IdInterface, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->execute();        
            $ResUsuarioInterface = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
            $countInsert = count($ResUsuarioInterface);
            // FECHANDO A CONSULTA
            $stm->closeCursor();    

        if ($countInsert == 0) {
            try {

                // INSERT USUÁRIO X INTERFACE           
                $crud = $conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO gasUsuarioInterface (IdUsuario, IdInterface) VALUES (?, ?)");
                $crud->bindParam(1, $IdUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $crud->bindParam(2, $IdInterface, PDO::PARAM_INT);      
                $crud->execute();                       

            } catch(PDOException $erro) {  

                // DESFAZ TRANSAÇÃO ATUAL
                $conexao->rollBack();

                $erro = $erro->getMessage();
                $retorno = array('codigo' => '0', 'mensagem' => ' Erro ao deletar interfaces para o usuário. Tente novamente [4]. ::$erro');                
                $conexao = null;        

                // RETORNO DE MENSAGEM
                echo json_encode($retorno);
                exit();                 

            }           
        }
    }   

    $conexao->commit();

} catch (Exception $e) {    

    // DESFAZ TRANSAÇÃO ATUAL
    $conexao->rollBack();   
    $retorno = array('codigo' => '0', 'mensagem' => ' Ocorreu um erro na gravação, tente novamente [5]. ::$erro');              
    $conexao = null;        

    // RETORNO DE MENSAGEM
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();     
}

$retorno = array('codigo' => '1', 'mensagem' => ' Direito de Acesso inserido com sucesso'); 

// FECHA CONEXÃO
$conexao = null;        

// RETORNO DE MENSAGEM
echo json_encode($retorno);
exit();
```

Comment: Apesar de ter conseguido fazer o que buscava, ficou faltando uma resposta conclusiva a como utilizar o `finally`no php