# Como usar Try Catch em um insert

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Como faço para utilizar um try catch para me retornar um erro de um insert que não foi inserido no banco de dados. Por exemplo

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nome,email,senha,telefone) VALUES (:nome,:email,:senha,:telefone)");
   $sql->bindValue(":nome",$nome);
   $sql->bindValue(":email",$email);
   $sql->bindValue(":senha",md5($senha));
   $sql->bindValue(":telefone",$telefone);
   $sql->execute();
```

Como eu posso fazer verificação para saber se foi realmente inserido e se não, me retornar o erro.

Answer (score 4):

Ao inves de usar a Exception use o PDOException[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu não entendo, ele não entra no catch para me informar o erro, mesmo eu forçando o erro no insert.

Answer (score 2):

Por padrão o PDO emite erros em consulta mal sucedidas, uma vez que erros e exceptions são coisas distintas especialmente no php.

A maneira mais simples de tratar uma falha é pegar o resultado de [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, email) VALUES (:nome,:email,:senha)");
$sql->bindValue(":nome",$nome);
$sql->bindValue(":email",$email);

if(!$sql->execute()){
    print_r($sql->errorInfo());
}
```

Se realmente precisar de exceptions deve sinalizar isso no construtor informando o quarto argumento com o array de opções ou via [`setAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php). A configuração que deve ser modificada é `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` e o respectivo valor é  `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`

Exemplo no construtor:

```
$opcoes = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=catalogo', 'root', 'root', $opcoes);
```

Exemplo via `setAttribute()`

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=catalogo', 'root', 'root');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Ao trabalhar com exceptions lembre sempre de qual problema deseja resolver ou seja capture apenas a exception mais especifica (a qual dará um tratamento diferente) no caso [PDOException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php).

```
$opcoes = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=catalogo', 'root', 'root', $opcoes);

try{
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO erro de sintaxe");
    $sql->bindValue(":nome",$nome);
    $sql->bindValue(":email",$email);

    $sql->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e){
  echo 'pokemon capturado com sucesso!11';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No caso você teria que trabalhar com a classe de exceções do php a classe (Exception), eu coloquei um exemplo básico aqui seguindo a linha do seu código, porém existe uma maneira mais correta de se trabalhar com isso.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.exceptions.php

```
try
{

   $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nome,email,senha,telefone) VALUES (:nome,:email,:senha,:telefone)");
   $sql->bindValue(":nome",$nome);
   $sql->bindValue(":email",$email);
   $sql->bindValue(":senha",md5($senha));
   $sql->bindValue(":telefone",$telefone);
   $sql->execute();

}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Ele não entra no catch, mesmo eu forçando o erro. Não sei porque.

Comment: Qual é a versão do php que você está utilizando? E no seu php.ini você já verificou se a opção de erros do php está habilitada para ser mostrada na tela? Talvez isso esteja mais relacionado em como está configurado o seu ambiente de desenvolvimento ou ambiente de produção.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde!

O método execute() do PDO retorna um booleano que indica se houve sucesso ou falha na execução do SQL (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.execute.php).

No seu caso, você pode fazer assim:

```
public function insereDados($nome, $email, $senha, $telefone) {
    if (!$nome || !$email || !$senha || !$telefone) {
        throw new DadosNaoPreenchidosException("Dados incompletos!");
    }

    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nome,email,senha,telefone) VALUES (:nome,:email,:senha,:telefone)");
    $sql->bindValue(":nome",$nome);
    $sql->bindValue(":email",$email);
    $sql->bindValue(":senha",md5($senha));
    $sql->bindValue(":telefone",$telefone);
    $sucesso = $sql->execute();
    if (!$sucesso) {
        throw new SqlException("Mensagem de erro");
    }
}
```

Você pode criar exceptions para tratá-las individualmente fora do método que a chama, assim: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.exceptions.extending.php

```
class SqlException extends SystemException {
    public __construct($mensagem) {
        parent::__construct($mensagem, 0);
    }
}
```

E depois, você trata suas exceptions na chamada dos métodos:

```
//faz alguma coisa
try {
    $obj->insereDados("João da Silva", "joao@dominio.com.br", "123", "(11) 1111-1111");
} catch (DadosIncompletosException $e) {
    echo "Dados não preenchidos";
} catch (SqlException $e) {
    echo "Erro ao executar o SQL";
}
```

Comment: A ideia e boa e funciona, mas eu tentei usar diretamente com tray catch, e de forma alguma, mesmo forçando erro, ele não acessa catch para me apresentar o erro.

Comment: você pode adicionar um trecho do seu código para análise?

Comment: O seu codigo funcionou, mas queria usar try catch direto, sem tratar o erro, mas usando metodos mecionados pelas pessoas ele não entra no catch.

Comment: E se você usasse um dos modos de [manipulação de erros](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.error-handling.php) do PDO? 
`$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Answer (score 0):

Em minha opnição a melhor forma de utilizar um bloco de exceção relacionado ao banco de dados é utilizando [PDO::beginTransaction](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.begintransaction.php).

Da uma olhada no item **Aplicação de regras de negócio quando uma exceção ocorre** da respota: [Para que servem os Blocos Try/Catch e quando devem ser utilizados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58536/para-que-servem-os-blocos-try-catch-e-quando-devem-ser-utilizados/424523#424523)