# Como utilizar o controller em uma aplicação java

Tags: java, mvc, spring, controller

Pessoal estou iniciando em programação e gostaria de tirar uma dúvida que não quer calar, como utilizar o controller de maneira correta seja ele sendo utilizado em um modelo design pattern ou ate mesmo em frameworks como spring mvc, VRaptor etc...

Exemplo:

Tenho uma aplicação de java que realiza cadastrado de usuário nela possuo um modelo(Usuario), controllerUsuario e um DaoUsuario quando realizar o login ou acrescentar qualquer outro tipo de tela que precise de uma regra de negócio ou que receba requisições devo criar outro controller?

Exemplo:

Preciso efetuar login e manter os dados do usuário para aquela sessão então devo criar um novo controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando está falando de `Controller`. Acredito que esteja falando da  [arquitetura MVC](https://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-padrao-mvc/29308) (*Model-View-Controller*). Quando utilizamos o padrão MVC termos como objetivo separar a aplicação em 3 camadas. A regra de negócios (*Model*) da interface do usuário (*View*) e do **fluxo da aplicação** (*Controller*).

Até este momento, não envolvemos nenhuma linguagem de programação para conceitualizar o que é um *controller*. Este não é um conceito de uma linguagem específica, muito menos um design pattern. **É um padrão de arquitetura de software**.

Falando especialmente sobre o *controller*. Seu principal objetivo é direcionar o fluxo da aplicação mapeando e direcionado as ações recebida (*request*) pela camada da apresentação para os respectivos serviços da aplicação.

Os serviços, detentores das regras de negócio, manipulam as informações vindas via *request* e retornam a *response* para o *controller* devolver para a aplicação.

Pense na seguinte analogia sobre o *controller*, como sendo um garçom que busca o pedido e devolve a comida. Ele não cozinha. É apenas um intermediário entre o cozinheiro e o cliente. Desta mesma forma o *controller* busca servir como uma camada intermediária entre a camada de apresentação e a lógica.

Por fim, para compreender a teoria, vamos a prática. Irei utilizar o [framework spark](http://sparkjava.com/documentation) para ilustrar nosso exemplo. Vamos assumir que a url da nossa aplicação é: `http://localhost:8000/`.

Segue outro exemplo em [PHP usando Laravel](https://blog.especializati.com.br/rotas-no-laravel/). Boa leitura para entender o que é uma rota. Recomendo.

Primeiramente toda requisição que vem do *front-end*, chega ao *back-end* através das [rotas da aplicação](http://sparkjava.com/documentation#routes). Vamos assumir que nossa rota é `debitos`, logo, a url ficará assim: `http://localhost:8000/debitos`.

```
// end-point debitos
path("/debitos", (request, response) -> {
    get("/filtros", DebitosController::filter);
    post("/mensal", DebitosController::mensal);
    post("/diario", DebitosController::diários);
});
```

As rotas do `Spark` se encarregam de entregar as informações `Request` ao `Controller::metodo` que especificamos na rota. Aqui começa a intermediação do `controller` entre a aplicação e a lógica do sistema.

O `controller`, por sua vez, recebe as informações e passa para o serviço manipular/utilizar como a regra de negócio quiser.

```
public class DebitosController {
    public static String filtro(Request request, Response response) {
        //pelo request ser um get e apenas uma informação não precisei transformar num objeto
        String filtro = request.queryParams("filtro");

        //serviço para tratar apenas da resposta
        ResponseService apiResponse = new ResponseService(response);

        //serviço para tratar apenas do request (os filtros)   
        FiltroService dateFilter = new DateFilterService(button);

        try {
            dateFilter.execute();
            apiResponse.setResult(dateFilter.getResponse());
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            apiResponse.setError(exception);
        }

        return apiResponse.json();
    }
    public static String mensal(Request request, Response response) {
        //converto os dados do request num objeto com getters e setters
        MensalRequest mensalRequest = new Gson().fromJson(request.body(), MensalRequest.class);

        //serviço para tratar apenas da resposta
        ResponseService apiResponse = new ResponseService(response);

        //serviço para tratar apenas do request (dados mensais)  
        MensalService mensal = new MensalService(mensalRequest);

        try {
            mensal.execute();
            apiResponse.setResult(mensal.getResponse());
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            apiResponse.setError(exception);
        }

        return apiResponse.json();
    }

    public static String diario(Request request, Response response) {
        //converto os dados do request num objeto com getters e setters
        DiarioRequest diarioRequest = new Gson().fromJson(request.body(), DiarioRequest.class);

        //serviço para tratar apenas da resposta
        ResponseService apiResponse = new ResponseService(response);

        //serviço para tratar apenas do request (dados diarios) 
        DiarioService diario = new DiarioService(debtRequest);

        try {
            diario.execute();
            apiResponse.setResult(diario.getResponse());
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            apiResponse.setError(exception);
        }

        return apiResponse.json();
    }
}
```

Agora vamos as explicações:

- Repare que para capturar a `request` e transfirmar num objeto eu utilizo o método `fromJson()` do `new Gson()`. É bem simples de utilizar. Segue exemplos: [exemplo 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314813/json-gson-fromjson-java-objects) e [exemplo 2](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=com.google.gson.Gson&method=fromJson);
- Criei um serviço específico para tratar para tratar e principalmente **padronizar a estrutura de resposta da aplicação**. O `response`;
- Criei um outro serviço exclusivo para tratar a lógica da aplicação. Nele eu utilizo um [contrato (interfaces)](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/interfaces/) para que todos os serviços relacionados a este funcionalidade tenham os mesmos métodos. Por isso, todos serviços `MensalService, FiltroService, DiarioService` contêm os mesmos métodos: `execute()` e `getResponse()`.
- Sobre o `controller`: O ideal é um controller por contexto/responsabilidade. No exemplo eu te mostrei o `controller` responsável pelas rotas `Debitos`. Vamos assumir que aplicação contém outro responsabilidade: `Creditos`, o correto seria criar um `controller` para "controlar" as rotas da funcionalidade `Creditos`. Resumindo: Um `controller` contexto/responsabilidade.
- Por fim, o retorno a resposta para o front em formato json `return apiResponse.json()`, porque neste exemplo a aplicação é uma [API Rest](https://www.devmedia.com.br/construindo-uma-api-restful-em-java/29904).

Obs.:

- Segue curso sobre [API Rest](https://www.udemy.com/api-restful-avancada-spring-boot-java-8/?utm_source=adwords-learn&utm_medium=udemyads&utm_campaign=INTL-AW-PROS-TECH-PT-DSA-PT-BRA_._ci__._sl_BRA_._vi_TECH_._sd_All_._la_PT_._&utm_content=deal4584&utm_term=_._ag_46964614946_._ad_226264569570_._de_c_._dm__._pl__._ti_aud-299743148867:dsa-376693965516_._li_1001634_._pd__._&gclid=CjwKCAjwuO3cBRAyEiwAzOxKsrCFEzvYp33sq5jjfEVCAfjJry9iuPcZwU8tB3ox7w45YWmM_rHzCBoCevAQAvD_BwE).
- [Como construir e testar uma API em Java utilizando o Postman](https://medium.com/assertqualityassurance/como-construir-e-testar-uma-api-em-java-utilizando-o-postman-baae69d8b8aa)
- [Rest e Java](https://www.devmedia.com.br/guia/rest-e-java/36819)

Comment: Só para que não haja dúvidas...
Então eu devo usar um controller para toda a minha aplicação pois o mesmo realiza o meio campo na minha aplicação assim como no seu exemplo do garçom, então eu devo realizar o processamento dos dados no meu service e apenas enviar a reposta para o meu controller para que ele possa devolver a resposta para a view, certo?

Comment: Se eu entendi bem sua dúvida. Usar um único `controller` para toda a aplicação? Não. O ideal é um `controller` por contexto/responsabilidade. No exemplo eu te mostrei o `controller` responsável pelas rotas `Debitos`. Vamos assumir que aplicação contém outro responsabilidade: `Creditos`, o correto seria criar um `controller` para "controlar" as rotas da funcionalidade  `Creditos`. Resumindo: Um controlercontexto/responsabilidade.

Answer (score 0):

A ideia principal do **MVC** é separar o código que cria e manipula os dados do código que apresenta os dados.
No caso de um login, quem vai receber os dados da requisição é o Controller, mas não é ele que vai manipular esses dados, então, ele delega essa tarefa para um outro responsável, eventualmente um Service. Após o Service concluir o processamento, é gerado o resultado que será devolvido para o Controller. Esse resultado contém os dados (Model) e a View que vai mostrar estes dados para o usuário.