# Arquitetura MVC - Windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, mvc

Como implementar o padrão MVC utilizando Windows forms? Gostaria de entender melhor como ficariam separadas as Views, Controllers e Models seguindo este modelo de desenvolvimento.

Comment: Um pouco de [conceito MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/329167/como-utilizar-o-controller-em-uma-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-java/329178#329178). Talvez ajude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Forms não segue nenhum conceito MVC, mas você pode implementar como quiser. Além disso, não faz sentido querer usar MVC no Winforms.

Em contrapartida, o Windows Forms é altamente modulável. As Views podem ser os `UserControls`, e já os `Controllers` e `Models` podem ser classes próprias, onde você define suas assinaturas com classes abstratas ou interfaces.

O .NET Framework têm o ASP.NET MVC, mas é aplicado para Web. Windows Forms e Web tem paradigmas distintos e por isso seguem *designs patterns* diferentes um do outro.

No Windows Forms, as `Views` é equivalente aos `System.Windows.Forms.Control`, mas você não trabalha diretamente com eles na prática. Você trabalha com o `Form` ou o `UserControl`. O Form é a janela do Windows (modal), o UserControl é um controle herdado diretamente do `Control`, que você pode inserir em qualquer lugar (assim como qualquer outro controle).

Todos componentes de contêineres de estrutura de WinForms herdam o `Control`, então você pode adicionar um objeto dentro do outro com o `panel1.Controls.Add(panel2)`.

Já as Models e Controllers podem ser classes sem um determinado padrão global. É só você implementar que no "`Controller`" irá puxar informações de uma `Model` e chamar a sua "View" (UserControl) com as informações obtidas da Model. A princípio, isso não existe no Windows Forms como algo nativo.

Como supramencionei, o Windows Forms não tem o objetivo de utilizar MVC. Não quer dizer que seja impossível implementar, mas você gastaria tempo e mesmo assim não poderia ficar bem como queria.

---

- Documentação do [UserControl](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.usercontrol).
- Documentação do [Form](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form).
- Documentação do [Control](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control).