# Implementação modelo MVC Java Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, mvc

No meu modelo estou acessando ClienteDAO pelo controlador do meu model Cliente como visto no exemplo abaixo.  Eu gostaria de saber se essa prática é correta para o modelo mvc, já que ambas as classes (controladorcliente e clientedao) estão em singleton.

Exemplo: verificar cpf

Classe controladorCliente

```
public boolean verificarCpfExistente(String cpf){
    if(ClienteDAO.getInstance().verificarCpf(cpf)==true)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Classe ClienteDAO

```
  public boolean verificarCpf(String cpf){
    String sql= "select * from cliente where cpf like ?";
      try {
         Connection conectar= conexao.getInstance().abrir();      
         PreparedStatement comando= conectar.prepareCall(sql);
         comando.setString(1,cpf);
         ResultSet resultset=comando.executeQuery(); 
         resultset.next();

         if(resultset.getString("cpf").equals(cpf))
             return true;          
      } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;      
        }
    return false;  
   }
```

projeto completo caso necessário: github.com/vvieira22/programavenda

Comment: Essa reposta pode te ajudar: [Entenda o conceito MVC da forma certa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/329167/como-utilizar-o-controller-em-uma-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-java/329178#329178)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o seu projeto for pequeno eu seguiria para uma estrutura parecida com essa:

```
/src/main/java/myName/appName/controller   
/src/main/java/myName/appName/model
/src/main/java/myName/appName/model/request
/src/main/java/myName/appName/model/response
/src/main/java/myName/appName/service
/src/main/java/myName/appName/dao
/src/main/java/myName/appName/vo(vo, dto, pojo)
/src/main/java/myName/appName/entity
```

A camada de controller jamais deve acessar diretamente a camada DAO, quem faz este intermédio é a camada de service.

Portanto para excluir um registro o controller deveria fazer uma chamada em um serviço que posteriormente irá chamar um serviço na camada DAO que irá efetivamente excluir o registro.

Outro ponto interessante é que o controller nunca deve acessar uma Entity, a entity deve ser convertida para um model response, antes de ser enviada ao controller.

E a camada de DAO não deve receber um model request, este deverá ser convertido para uma entity (caso necessário), antes da camada do DAO.

Comment: entendi, no caso da minha classe dao ser um singleton, tem problema eu acessar ela pelo controlador?, essa dao faz toda conexão no banco do cliente por isso um singleton, se um cpf do cliente existe, cadastra um novo cliente etc...

Comment: modifiquei a pergunta, vê se melhora a minha dúvida.