# Não tratar um catch é uma má prática?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react

Em meu sistema eu tenho a `store`, que é a responsável por manter o estado e também enviar as requisições http para o servidor. Um exemplo dela é esse método aqui:

```
async novoLancamento( valor: string ) {
this.loading.item = true; 
try { 
const lancamento = new Lancamento(); 
lancamento.valor = parseFloat( valor ); 

await this.saveAny( 
lancamento, 
rotaEvento.lancamento(this.item.id_evento )
);

this.helper.setAlert('Cadastrado'); 

} catch (e) { 
this.helper.setAlert('Erro');
throw e; 

} finally { 
this.loading.item = false; 
} 
}
```

Aí tenho um `Button` na minha `View` que chama esse método é faz uma ação caso de certo:

```
<Button 
icon="save" 
loading={this.store.loading.item} 
title="CADASTRAR" 
onClick={() => this.store.novoLancamento( this.state.valor ) 
.then( () => this.setState({ movimentacao: false })) 
} 
/>
```

Mas fazendo assim o compilador fica me mostrando esse alerta:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object]
```

Pelo que entendi é pelo fato de eu não capturar o `catch` lá no Buttom. Mas na minha estrutura não há necessidade de tratar ele, o que me importa é somente o `then`.

Então, minha pergunta é: esse meu código está errado? Ou seja, está desrespeitando alguma norma?

**Edit
Um colega aqui em baixo disse que não é uma boa prática relançar uma exceção. Fui pesquisar sobre o assunto, encontrei uma matéria no site da Mozilla MDN web docs que faz exatamente isso, relança uma exceção.

> Relançando uma exceção. Você pode usar throw para relançar uma exceção
>   após você pegá-la. O exemplo a seguir pega uma exceção com um valor
>   numérico e a relança se o valor for maior que 50. A exceção relançada
>   propaga para a função encapsuladora ou para o nível superior para que
>   o usuário a veja.
>
> ```
> try {
>    throw n; // lança uma exceção com um valor numérico
> } catch (e) {
>    if (e <= 50) {
>       // instruções para tratar exceções 1-50
>    } else {
>       // não pode tratar esta exceção então relança
>       throw e;
>    }
> }
> ```

Comment: O erro não acontece pelo fato de você não utilizar o `catch`. A pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58536/99718 tem algumas respostas que talvez ajude-o.

Comment: Tem outras perguntas que devem ajudar mais ainda. Esse uso está bem errado, talvez o async também. Exceção era o mecanismo de linguagens mais mal usado da programação, esse o async tomou o primeiro lugar.

Comment: @Maniero obrigado pela resposta. Se possível,  posta a forma correta de se fazer esse trabalho. 

Comment: Depende do contexto que não tem para acertar tudo. capturar exceção e lançar de novo não faz sentido. Pode começar ver por aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%c3%a7%c3%a3o?tab=Votes.